# Script does not run on command prompt as in PyScripter

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm developing a script in PyScripter. When I run it in PyScripter it runs fairly well.
However, the script contains two separate threads (one Thread object, and the main flow of the script). When I run the script from the Command prompt it gets stuck in the Thread. It gives no impression of executeing the main process, and it never ends, which it does when I run it inside PyScripter. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, use `timeout` in `join()` to put time constrain on the thread. For instance

```
....
yourThread = threading.Thread()
yourThread.start()
yourThread.join(10.0)
....
```

Instructions of multithreading checks [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Hope it helps you.

Comment: This thread class has a method called CloseThread(self) which is the only place where join() is called in the entire library. As it was written before, it did not have an explicit timeout time set, but putting one in there did not help. Should I put a call to the join()-method somewhere else, like in the __init__(self)-method?

Comment: No, join() should be invoked after start(). Are you sure join() in your CloseThread(self) has been invoked? Try to add a debug info to confirm.

Comment: It worked when I put a join() in the beginning of the thread. Is there any reason not to give the join() function a very small time argument? (In any scenario) My program seemed to work better the shorter time I set.

Comment: When yourthread.join() is invoked, it will wait until the thread terminates. When the timeout argument is not present or None, the operation will block until the thread terminates.In your case, shorter time equals better work, then you should give join() a timeout. BTW, a thread can be join()ed many times. If this helps you, please confirm it as an answer.